# Customize Gradle distribution plugin to generate tar.gz

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

i have to create tar.gz , below is my distribution setting in build.gradle

```
distributions { 
  main { 
   contents {
     into ("/")
     from libsDir
     include ‘.jar’
     rename '..jar’, “${project.name}.jar”
     from “env”
     include ‘*.conf’
    }
  }
}
```

Please suggest what changes i need to make to build.gradle in order to generate tar.gz file

Answer (score 5):

You can add:

```
plugins.withType(DistributionPlugin) {
    distTar {
        compression = Compression.GZIP
        extension = 'tar.gz'
    }
}
```

This will configure the `Tar` class.

Answer (score 3):

**With Gradle 6.x**

just add to `build.gradle`

```
distTar {
    compression = Compression.GZIP
    archiveExtension = "tar.gz"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the other solutions, this works for me:

```
tasks.withType(Tar) {
    compression = Compression.GZIP
    archiveExtension = 'tar.gz'
}
```

Tested with Gradle 6.8.

Comment: Similarly you can also specify options for both `distTar` and `distZip` simultaneously by using the task `AbstractArchiveTask` instead of `Tar` as parameter. In my case this was very useful for specifying a `duplicatesStrategy` for both.

Answer (score 0):

gradle 7.6 with kotlin DSL

```
tasks.distTar {
    compression = Compression.GZIP
    archiveExtension.set("tar.gz")
}
```